# Friend functions

Tags: class, encapsulation, friend

Just a simple question about the use of friend functions, or rather their usefulness.  Basically..

How are they useful?  If you've properly designed your classes, would there really be a need for friend functions?  What are cases where you'd want to use or not use them?  I'm told that they enhance encapsulation, but from my experiences, I've only used one friend function in the 7 years I've been coding.  After further examination and refactoring of my code, I realized I didn't even need to use it.  It seems like they somewhat violate encapsulation, rather than ehancing it.  This is probably due to my lack of knowledge in the area.

tldr; What is so useful about friend functions, when should/should not they be used, and how do they enhance encapsulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoever told you friend functions enhance encapsulation is plain wrong, they're the exact opposite. They truly have no place in a truly OOP world.

However, life is rarely perfect, and at times you'll need to call protected methods from other classes within your framework, without exposing them to the outside. C# and Java solved this problem very elegantly: they have an `internal` modifier (with slightly different meanings), but in C++ all you have is `friend`.

If you truly have been programming for 7 years without ever needing this construct, then you either make every method and variable in your class `public` or you don't use classes at all.

Comment: No, I actually don't make everything public, I've just never personally found a use for them.  However, I can see them being useful for objects communicating with each other.

Answer (score 1):

One scenario I can think of is when multiple projects share code.  Your class B needs to access private members in class A which is owned by a separate group.  If you cannot break the existing contract of that class you could add a friend method which does what you need it to without breaking anything for the other group.

Of course now with .NET 4 we have the ability to add dynamic methods to classes which eliminates my scenario completely.

Answer (score -1):

Please see - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friend_function

Comment: That article describes what a friend but not what the OP is asking about. "What is so useful about friend functions, when should/should not they be used, and how do they enhance encapsulation?"